# How to fix "There are too many LockService operations against the same script" error?

Tags: google-apps-script, locking

I have a public add-on that utilises Google Apps Script Lock Service to prevent reading a spreadsheet before writes are made.

```
var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
var success = lock.tryLock(240000); // 4 minutes
if (!success) {
console.warn('Could not obtain lock after 4 minutes.');
return;
}
//perform some function then release lock
lock.releaseLock();
```

I continue to receive the error message:

> There are too many LockService operations against the same script.

Originally I thought this error was 'user based' and there was potentially a quota against the number of Lock Service operations *per user*, however I recently started seeing it appear more often against 30+ users in the past few days.

- Is there a limit to the number of LockService operations *per user*
  or *per script*?
- If so, what is the limit?

I don't see any reference to a quota within [Google Apps Script quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Nor do I see any reference to a quota within the [LockService documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a report about this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112384851

It appears this might happen sporadically. A Google employee responded with the following:

> Just to give an update to this: The Apps Script team recommends:
>
> 1)  Use a try/catch block around the LockService call, and assume that an error means "lock was not acquired" (whatever that means for the logic the script is trying to do).
>
> 2)  If "lock was not acquired" means "script should try again", then put a sleep in there of a few seconds (maybe even exponential backoff) before retrying the LockService operation.
>
> We do not have any other solution for this at the moment and might have an update once certain changes are made to Apps Script.

Comment: Seems like a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112384851#comment19) of Google App Script, which has been solved by Google in Nov 2019.

Comment: @ebk Unfortunately it has not been solved! I get this error constantly, on both `tryLock()` and `releaseLock()`, even if there is only one instance of my script running.

Answer (score 3):

This likely happens when there are multiple triggers trying to access the same Google Sheet simultaneously. Google Quota page doesn't document the exact limits anywhere but try reducing the number of triggers associated with the sheet and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Amit, very strange that it would related to triggers but I'll give it a go and see if it improves.

Comment: I had two triggers per user which I scaled back to one per user overnight and unfortunately continue to see this error in full force. It appears there is an unadvertised limit on the number of locks *per script*. I have temporarily amended it from a Document Lock to a Script Lock. Not ideal, but it should solve it temporarily until I find an alternate method.

Comment: I' m experencing the same problem with ScriptLock, sporadically though.